# MySQLSyntaxErrorException for a join command which is working fine on MySQL workbench

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jdbc, syntax-error

```
String query = "select Books.BookId, Books.Title, Book_Loans.BranchId, count(Book_Loans.BookLoanId) as NoOfCopies from (Book_Loans join Books"
+ "on (Book_Loans.BookId = Books.BookId)) where Books.BookId = ? group by (Book_Loans.BranchId)";
        preparedStatement = connect.prepareStatement(query);
        preparedStatement.setLong(1, bookId);
        resultSet = preparedStatement.executeQuery();
        while(resultSet.next()) {
            System.out.println("BookId:"+resultSet.getLong(1)+"\nTitle:"+resultSet.getString(2)+"\nBranchId:"+resultSet.getLong(3)+"\nNoOfCopies:"+resultSet.getInt(4)+"\n");
```

I am trying to execute the above code snippet but I am getting MySQLSyntaxErrorException as below:

```
Exception in thread "main" com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(Book_Loans.BookId = Books.BookId)) where Books.BookId = 75 group by (Book_Loans' at line 1
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:425)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:408)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:944)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3976)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3912)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2530)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2683)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2486)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:1858)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeQuery(PreparedStatement.java:1966)
    at libraryModel.CopiesCheckedOutFromEachBranchForABook.numberOfCheckedOutCopies(CopiesCheckedOutFromEachBranchForABook.java:36)
    at libraryModel.Main.main(Main.java:47)
```

The tables related  to the queries are as below:
Books(**BookId**, AuthorName, Title, (Publisher)Name)
Book_Loans(**BookLoanId**, DateOut, DueDate, BranchId, BookId, CardNo)

I am trying to display the number of copies of books checked out from each branch by asking the user to enter the branchId. The query is working fine when I ran it on MySQL workbench but giving me syntax error on Eclipse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing a space between "books" and "on". Add it and you should be fine.

Comment: ohh yes!! thank you so much. Couldn't find this for so long

Answer (score 2):

The SQL query is not correct You got to add a space between Books and on. ALso, there is no need to put additional parenthesis

Use:

```
String query = "select Books.BookId, Books.Title, Book_Loans.BranchId, count(Book_Loans.BookLoanId) as NoOfCopies from Book_Loans join Books on Book_Loans.BookId = Books.BookId where Books.BookId = ? group by Book_Loans.BranchId";
```

Answer (score 1):

Your query doesn't make sense. You are saying to aggregate by the branch, and then including information about books.  In most databases -- and even in the more recent versions of MySQL -- this would fail.

Your query should look more like this:

```
select bl.BranchId, count(*) as NumCopies
from Book_Loans bl join
     Books b
     on bl.BookId = b.BookId
where b.BookId = ? 
group by bl.BranchId;
```

If you want to include information about the book, then the proper way would be to use aggregation functions or to include the columns in the `group by`:

```
select bl.BranchId, count(*) as NumCopies, b.BookId, b.Title
from Book_Loans bl join
     Books b
     on bl.BookId = b.BookId
where b.BookId = ? 
group by bl.BranchId, b.BookId, b.Title;
```

Notes that table aliases make a query easier to write and read.

Of course, once you get the query correct, you need to implement it correctly in your application, including getting the spacing correct around the lines of the query.